# python selenium clicking a list object

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am trying to click 1 Min button on this [site](https://www.investing.com/technical/technical-analysis)

below is my python code

```
url = 'https://www.investing.com/technical/technical-analysis'
driver.get(url)
events = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "section#leftColumn")))
print("Required elements found")
events.find_element(By.XPATH,"//a[text()='1 Min']").click()
```

Am getting the following error:
events.find_element(By.XPATH,"//a[text()='1 Min']").click()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find_element'

What can I change in the code to click the '1 Min' button succesfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `'for'` loop to iterate through all the elements in `'events'` element:

```
events = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "section#leftColumn")))
print("Required elements found")
for event in events:
    event.find_element(By.XPATH,"//a[text()='1 Min']").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change the last line to;
driver.find_element

Also you can check for that XPATH with WebDriverWait until located.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).